# During the N7: Fuel Reactors mission, if I aid Captain Riley's team, do I lose a squad member?

Tags: mass-effect-3

During the N7: Fuel Reactors mission, after I restart the reactor, I'm given the choice to send help to Captain Riley.  If I don't send help, they die.  If I send help, can I save them or will it cost me a squad member?

[image: Choose your path]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you send a squad member to help, then everyone will survive, however, you will be down one squad member for the remainder of the mission, making it harder.

Comment: In this case it's a Brute and a wave or two of other Reaper ground troops.  It's pretty doable without your second squadmate, so long as you've not had trouble with the combat in this mission thus far.

Comment: Interestingly however, there are no repercussions (other than Renegade points) from letting Captain Riley die.

Answer (score 0):

No, your squad member will survive. However if you don't send someone, Riley's squad will perish. If Riley survives you can then recommend her for the N7 program at the Spectre office.